# Javascript or Jquery Calendar which should hide previous dates from current date and also Week ends

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Need a calendar script in Javascript or Jquery which should have the option like disabling all the previous dates from the current date and also disable the Saturday's and Sunday's too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **[jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)**

1. you can disable previous dates, by using `minDate` and `maxDate` options
2. check this out [disabling Saturdays and Sundays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida)

Comment: I am not much familiar with jquery and javascript so can you tell Where can i exactly paste that content

Comment: you can do something like this inside your js file 
 `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );` where `".selector"` is the element that you want the calendar view to pop out

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple calendar script in javascript:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>M</td> <td>T</td> <td>W</td> <td>T</td> <td>F</td> <td>S</td> <td>S</td>
</tr>

<script language="JavaScript"> <!--

// find the first day of the current month
function firstDay() {
   d = new Date();   // d is today's date
   d.setDate(1);     // set d to the 1st of this month
   day = d.getDay(); // day of week - 0=Sunday, 1=Monday... etc.
   if (day==0) {
      return 6;
   } else {
      return day-1;
   }
}

var week = 0; // week of the month
var weekDay = 0; // day of the week
var day; // day of the month
var startingDay = firstDay(); // day the month starts, 0 to 6 

for (week=0; week<=5; week++) {
   document.write("<tr>");
   for (weekDay=1; weekDay<=7; weekDay++) {
      document.write("<td>");
      day = 7*week+weekDay;
      day -= startingDay;
      if (day>0 && day<=31) { document.write(day); }
      document.write("</td>");
   }
   document.write("</tr>");
}

--> </script>

<table>
```

It's not disabling past dates or week-ends but it's so simple that you will probably be able to adapt it.