# how to disable the holidays and saturdays and sundays from jquery calendar in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

in my application using jquery date picker,my problem is in ui customer select the date , customer select the weekends(satuardays, sundays) and USA holidays(01-01-2011 etc- but year changed based on pc date) disabled (not selected). i am writing code like this

```
$(function () {
$('#txtPaymentDate').datepick({ onDate: $.datepick.noWeekends, showTrigger: '#calImg'
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
```

From the docs: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/noWeekends

Comment: @hmk then create use beforeShowDay to call a funciton strips out weekends and holidays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida

Comment: ok all ready saw that link but it is not working how to add the showTrigger: '#calImg'(it is a image) in that code pls help me