# How can i write a custom function to disable some dates in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to write a function in jQuery/Javascript of our own so that it should disable US Holidays and Week ends.

Can any one give me an idea to write the function and how to call that function as per my need

Comment: `$(people).ready(function(){ var work; if ( holiday = true ){ g0 > t0 > work } else { work === 0-24 } });`

Comment: I need to have a jquery function which should disable all weekends and u.s Holdiays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is posible, Adam Bellaire gives a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holida) on how to implement for the date picker. This should be pretty easy to implement in your design.

Answer (score 0):

http://michaelthompson.org/technikos/holidays.php has what looks like decent a solution in C that looks pretty easy to turn into Javascript