# jQuery ui datepicker, select range of whole weeks only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to create a jQuery ui datepicker that will let users choose a start week of the year, and an ending week of the year. IE: Always Sunday - Saturday. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DatePicker can restrict a user's selection, but only as far as restricting the user between two dates (`minDate` and `maxDate` options). As far as I'm aware, there's no built in functionality that can restrict selection to only Sundays or Saturdays.

DatePicker does however have a means of calculating the week of a user's selection with the following snippet of code:

```js
$.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText))
```

You can see how this could be utilised in the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/weDg9/) (read below, first).

The only problem with this is that the ISO-week always starts with a Monday. So even though in the demo above I have set Sunday to be the first day of the week, if you try selecting the date `Wed 7th March 2012` you'll see in the datapicker it shows as week 9, where the ISO-week will return 10. I left it in on purpose to show you this pitfall.

Although this doesn't provide a direct solution to your problem, hopefully it'll help in determining if you should use DatePicker at all to produce your desired functionality.

**edit**

Actually, just found this question which might be of use to you, looks like it's possible : [Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid)