# Calendar based on available dates

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, calendar

I have dates in my script related to some teaching lessons. Each lesson has a maximum number of students. When a lesson reached this amount, all the other users will be not able to register to that lesson. I did it in a PHP format with MySQL using HTML-SELECT and Javascript, but I need a way to show a **Calendar** with the available dates. I've tried to use the jQuery, but I couldn't control the accessible dates on the calendar.

Can you suggest what I need to do?

Comment: I tried to use a basic SELECT menu, but I want the user see the available dates in a calendar. for example the not available dates will be without link, and the available one with blue link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jquery ui datepicker. You are able to control dates without issue. There are many topics about it here on stackoverflow as well as many examples at jqueryui.com

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

If you decide to use this, here is a topic that explains in great detail how exclude specific dates, etc. [Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid)