# jquery UI datepicker, is it possible to make it so some dates are unselectable?

Tags: jquery, datetime, widget

My client wants a program which will use a datepicker which will have certain dates unclickable, disabled, or greyed out because they are full or not applicable for her business hours.

Is there a way to, given an array of dates, either alert the user that the option is bot doable or block it out/grey out, so it cant be selected as a date?  I would prefer the later option.

I was looking through the Jquery UI fatepicker tool to try to figure this out.

Link:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David Walsh posted about this some time ago...

http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days

You need to use the 'beforeShowDay' event

Comment: I think i was searching Stackoverflow with the wrong search parameters.