# How to use JQuery to iterate elements of a class

Tags: jquery

In my MVC application, I can assign the datepicker class to all of the input boxes requiring date fields.
Previously I could then set up my datepicker with the following properties (which worked);

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({ 
  showOn: 'both', 
  dateFormat: 'dd MM yy', 
  changeMonth: true, 
  changeYear: true, 
  yearRange: 'c-1:c+1', 
  beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays });
```

Now I need to assign a date of birth datepicker that requires a different setup. So for that element I wrap the element as follows;

```
<span class="allDates"><%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.Dob)%></span>
```

So when my View is rendered, the Html from View Source looks like;

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
        <label for="Employee_Dob">Date of Birth</label>
    </td>                    
    <td colspan="2">
        <span class="allDates">
            <input class="datePicker" id="Employee_Dob" name="Employee.Dob" type="text" value="" />
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now my jquery does not work - I imagine this is a simple fix for someone;

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").each(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("allDates")) {
            $(this).datepicker({ showOn: 'both', dateFormat: 'dd MM yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: 'c-100:c' });
        } else {
            $(this).datepicker({ showOn: 'both', dateFormat: 'dd MM yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: 'c-1:c+1', beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have the `noWeekendsOrHolidays` function defined in your code? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/501943/1331430

Comment: What does the HTML look like when then input is generated in your View?

Comment: I know, it was more so that I can see what classes you have, any ID attribute, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your DOB field an extra class, then create the datepicker again on it, with a different set of options:

`class="datepicker dob"`

```
$(".datepicker.dob").datepicker('destroy').datepicker({ 
    showOn: 'both',
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: 'c-100:c'
});
```

Or to recreate the options on only that specific datepicker:

```
$("#Employee_Dob.datePicker").datepicker('destroy').datepicker({ 
    showOn: 'both',
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: 'c-100:c'
});
```

Comment: I tried something similar with #Employee_Dob.datePicker, but this does not overwrite the $(".datePicker").datepicker assignment, which is why I am trying to find a solution with the each iterator.

Comment: @arame3333 See updated answer.  Try destroying the datepicker options first, then recreating them.

Comment: Yes that did it. Thanks, I would never have guessed that as the answer, I did not know about destroy. Very useful. I will give you the uptick when you change your answer to show $("#Employee_Dob.datePicker")

Comment: It is probably better to have the selector remain class-based, as the code then gets reapplied to any datepicker that is for a date of birth.  Of course, you might not want to do this or you feel that there won't ever be another DOB date picker in your application but, from a general coding point of view, it is better to create code that is reusable and dynamic.

Comment: I agree. It is tricking injecting classes into MVC Editor Templates which is why my plan B was to use a Span element. I can probably do that as well.

Comment: So $(".allDates").children(".datePicker") is the solution I am using.