# Jquery Datepickler enable only few days in a week

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code for `Jquery UI Datepicker`. How can I disable dates which are specific to certain days in a week?
i.e. I would like to display only days from today's date and would like to enable only
`Monday and Friday` in a week, rest of the days should be disabled.

Markup:

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text">
```

Code

```
$(function () {
   var date1 = new Date;
   date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
   date1.setDate(10);
   var date2 = new Date;
   date2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
   date2.setDate(23);
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
       beforeShowDay: function (date) {
           return [date < date1 || date > date2, ""];
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Missing constructor: `new Date;` vs `new Date();`

Comment: I'm 90% sure this is impossible with this extension. There is no date changed event and you can only specify sequential dates out of the box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the jQuery UI Datepicker be made to disable Saturdays and Sundays (and holidays)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the specific day number  in beforeshowday function

```
 $(function() {
    $("#datepic").datepicker(
    { beforeShowDay: function(day) {
        var day = day.getDay();
        if (day == 2 || day == 5) {
            return [false, "somecssclass"]
        } else {
            return [true, "someothercssclass"]
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have created a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rq77k/) as per your solution which is fine except for a few things. 1) What exactly should I add somecssclass? 2) As you can see in demo, I can manually enter a date which is not Tuesday or Friday. How can I prevent this?

Comment: swetha, I have managed the second part by setting `readonly="readonly"`.

Comment: Somecssclass means the dates which you want to disable will be added with that class and the other will be useful for adding css to remaining thats an optional one                                             For your second question just add some class to that input field and on keypress you can give an alert msg or u can disable user to enter keys                                                                       OR try using this piece of code                                <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly" />