# jquery datepicker calendar how to disable sunday date or any day?

Tags: jquery

I am working on hrm related site I have face one problem that uploading attending sheet select jquery date picker calender date. In calander require not select sunday date for upload attendance sheet.

please help how to disable sunday date in jquery datepicker ?

Comment: So where is you code?How can we disable anything without looking at it???

Comment: this would be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use beforeShowDate event of DatePicker like below:

```
$("#textboxid").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
var day = date.getDay();
return [day != 0,''];
}
})​​​​​;​
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope something like this may help u mate... :)

```
$('#noSunday').datepicker({ 
        beforeShowDay: noSunday, 
 }); 

      function noSunday(date){ 
         return [date.getDay() != 0, ''];
      };
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zXFGN/